# appending another variable besides what was iterated inside list comprehension (python)

Tags: python

i've got this for loop below and it works fine but I wanted to try and convert it to a list comprehension

```
   medname = []
   for med in medicationsTextBoxLocatorTextBox:
        if med.get_attribute("value") != "":
            a = med.get_attribute("value")
            medname.append(a)
```

I've tried this:

```
medname = [med for med in medicationsTextBoxLocatorTextBox if med.get_attribute("value") != ""]
```

now this populates the list fine but what I discovered was that I don't know how to do this part `a = med.get_attribute("value")`I don't know how to incorporate that into the list comprehension

i've tried:

```
medname = [a = med.get_attribute("value") for med in medicationsTextBoxLocatorTextBox if med.get_attribute("value") != ""]
```

sure enough it fails.

how do we put `a = med.get_attribute("value")` inside the list comprehension?

Im fairly new to python and have shun away from list comprehensions but decided to try it out for the first time today.

so how do we do it?

Comment: `medname = [med.get_attribute('value') for med in ...]`

Comment: wow that was easy :/

but let's say if another variable were to be put in there like the problem above? how do we do that?

Comment: It doesn't matter that you used another variable to capture the attribute of the iteration variable. The thing about list comprehensions is that you can't create another variable on the fly, without manipulating `globals()`, which is highly inadvisable

Comment: ok :/ bummer thank you for the answer but you didn't answer my question.

you only commented it I can't select that as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reason to set `a` equal to anything because it will just be replaced the next time around. Try this:

```
medname = [med.get_attribute('value') for med in medicationsTextBoxLocatorTextBox if med.get_attribute('value') != ""]
```

If you really want to set a variable, then you'll just have to use a regular for loop because list comprehension is only meant for creating lists, not carrying out commands.

Comment: so you can't set "a" to anything? if i were to somehow need that it cannot be in a list comprehension?

Comment: @HalcyonAbrahamRamirez Well, in your case, there is no reason to, but if you really have to, your best option is to just use the for loop you had earlier.

Comment: thank you very much for taking the time to answer my question. I appreciate it a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your above is you're not getting the attribute. Correct would be:

```
 medname = [med.get_attribute("value") for med in medicationsTextBoxLocatorTextBox if med.get_attribute("value") != ""]
```

Of course, this technically has redundant efforts, which can be problematic if `med.get_attribute` is expensive or stateful. In that case, you can use a generator expression:

```
values = (med.get_attribute("value") for med in  medicationsTextBoxLocatorTextBox)
medname = [value for value in values if value != ""]
```

Now the expression uses no intermediary data structures, and only calls `get_attribute` once per iteration.

Comment: this is interesting. A generator expression? I'll look into that too. I understand what the code is trying to say but I gotta dig in more to grasp it. thank you for your answer

Comment: @HalcyonAbrahamRamirez yeah! Generators! Kind of the best thing around in Python. Generator expressions are a special shorthand case of them. Check out https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/ for a good explanation of them and their utility.